# Firebase: Data retrieved from Firestore shows null

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to display the data I receive from the cloud function on the screen. I do receive the data from Firebase, but when displaying that data it shows null. **Here's the piece of code where a data should be displayed:**

```
children: [
                CustomText(text: appState.riderModel?.name ?? "Nada"),
              ],
```

**The code for handling incoming notifications:**

```
 Future handleOnMessage(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    _handleNotificationData(data);
    print('=====Message data=====: $data');
  }

  Future handleOnLaunch(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    _handleNotificationData(data);
    print('=====Message data=====: $data');
  }

  Future handleOnResume(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    _handleNotificationData(data);
    print('=====Message data=====: $data');
  }

  _handleNotificationData(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    hasNewRideRequest = true;
    rideRequestModel = RideRequestModel.fromMap(data['data']);
    print("Ride request model: $rideRequestModel");
    riderModel = await _riderServices.getRiderById(rideRequestModel.userId);
    print("Rider model: $riderModel");
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

**The debug console when app receives notification:**

```
I/flutter (21865): =====Message data=====: {destination_latitude: 5.8177188, distance_text: 8.1 km, destination: T.B.L. Cinemas, Lalla Rookhweg, Paramaribo, Suriname, destination_longitude: -55.2056041, distance_value: 8108, id: 81a28860-ea96-11ed-af87-7f47650afadb, type: RIDE_REQUEST, user_longitude: -55.2007486, userId: xQWYlU7FOdV85u8Vfh5Is64wS0J3, user_latitude: 5.7665181, username: Praveesh Ramroop}
```

**Here's the code for the notification model:**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class RideRequestModel {
  static const ID = "id";
  static const USERNAME = "username";
  static const USER_ID = "userId";
  static const DESTINATION = "destination";
  static const DESTINATION_LAT = "destination_latitude";
  static const DESTINATION_LNG = "destination_longitude";
  static const USER_LAT = "user_latitude";
  static const USER_LNG = "user_longitude";
  static const DISTANCE_TEXT = "distance_text";
  static const DISTANCE_VALUE = "distance_value";

  String _id;
  String _username;
  String _userId;
  String _destination;
  double _dLatitude;
  double _dLongitude;
  double _uLatitude;
  double _uLongitude;
  Distance _distance;

  String get id => _id;

  String get username => _username;

  String get userId => _userId;

  String get destination => _destination;

  double get dLatitude => _dLatitude;

  double get dLongitude => _dLongitude;

  double get uLatitude => _uLatitude;

  double get uLongitude => _uLongitude;

  Distance get distance => _distance;

  RideRequestModel.fromMap(Map data) {
    if (data != null) {
      String _d = data[DESTINATION];
      _id = data[ID];
      _username = data[USERNAME];
      _userId = data[USER_ID];
      _destination = _d.substring(0, _d.indexOf(','));
      _dLatitude = double.parse(data[DESTINATION_LAT]);
      _dLongitude = double.parse(data[DESTINATION_LNG]);
      _uLatitude = double.parse(data[USER_LAT]);
      _uLongitude = double.parse(data[USER_LAT]);
      _distance = Distance.fromMap({
        "text": data[DISTANCE_TEXT],
        "value": int.parse(data[DISTANCE_VALUE])
      });
      print(
          "RideRequestModel.fromMap(): _id = $_id, _username = $_username, _userId = $_userId, _destination = $_destination, _dLatitude = $_dLatitude, _dLongitude = $_dLongitude, _uLatitude = $_uLatitude, _uLongitude = $_uLongitude");
    }
  }
}

class Distance {
  String text;
  int value;

  Distance.fromMap(Map data) {
    text = data["text"];
    value = data["value"];
  }

  Map toJson() => {"text": text, "value": value};
}

class RequestModelFirebase {
  static const ID = "id";
  static const USERNAME = "username";
  static const USER_ID = "userId";
  static const DRIVER_ID = "driverId";
  static const STATUS = "status";
  static const POSITION = "position";
  static const DESTINATION = "destination";

  String _id;
  String _username;
  String _userId;
  String _driverId;
  String _status;
  Map _position;
  Map _destination;

  String get id => _id;
  String get username => _username;
  String get userId => _userId;
  String get driverId => _driverId;
  String get status => _status;
  Map get position => _position;
  Map get destination => _destination;

  RequestModelFirebase.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    _id = snapshot.data()[ID];
    _username = snapshot.data()[USERNAME];
    _userId = snapshot.data()[USER_ID];
    _driverId = snapshot.data()[DRIVER_ID];
    _status = snapshot.data()[STATUS];
    _position = snapshot.data()[POSITION];
    _destination = snapshot.data()[DESTINATION];
  }

  LatLng getCoordinates() =>
      LatLng(_position['latitude'], _position['longitude']);
}
```

**And here's the code for the notification service:**

```
import 'package:driver/helpers/constants.dart';
import 'package:driver/models/ride_Request.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class RideRequestServices {
  String collection = "requests";

  void updateRequest(Map<String, dynamic> values) {
    firebaseFiretore.collection(collection).doc(values['id']).update(values);
  }

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> requestStream({String id}) {
    CollectionReference reference = firebaseFiretore.collection(collection);
    return reference.snapshots();
  }

  Future<RequestModelFirebase> getRequestById(String id) =>
      firebaseFiretore.collection(collection).doc(id).get().then((doc) {
        return RequestModelFirebase.fromSnapshot(doc);
      });
}
```

**Finally, here below you'll see the cloud function in case that helps:**

```
export const rideRequestNotification = functions.firestore.document('requests/{requestId}').onCreate(
    async snapshot => {
        const rideRequet = snapshot.data();

        const tokens: string[] = []

        const drivers = await db.collection('drivers').get()   

        drivers.forEach(document => {
            
        console.log(`DATA: ${document.data().token}`);

            tokens.push(document.data().token)
        })


        
        const payload: admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
            notification: {
                title: "Ride request",
                body: `${rideRequet.username} is looking for a ride to ${rideRequet.destination.address}`,
                clickAction: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
            },
            data: {
                username: rideRequet.username,
                destination: rideRequet.destination.address,
                distance_text: rideRequet.distance.text,
                distance_value: rideRequet.distance.value.toString(),
                destination_latitude: rideRequet.destination.latitude.toString(),
                destination_longitude: rideRequet.destination.longitude.toString(),
                user_latitude: rideRequet.position.latitude.toString(),
                user_longitude: rideRequet.position.longitude.toString(),
                id: rideRequet.id,
                userId: rideRequet.userId,
                type: 'RIDE_REQUEST'

            }
        }

        console.log(`NUMBER OF TOKENS IS: ${tokens.length}`);

       return fcm.sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
    }
)
```